# PHP's date always returns January?

Tags: php, date

I'm writing a sign up form, and I have this:

```
<?php
for($j = 1; $j <= 12; $j++)
{
    $month = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, j, 1, 2000));
    echo '<option value="'.$month.'">'.$month.'</option>';
}
?>
```

The problem is that my select box shows 'January' 12 times, but I want January, February, March etc... through December. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a dollar sign in front of "j" here:

```
$month = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, j, 1, 2000));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

```
$month = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $j, 1, 2000));
```

Notice the $ on the j

Answer (score 1):

It's $j.

```
$month = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $j, 1, 2000));
```

Answer (score 1):

Should it be

```
mktime(0, 0, 0, $j , 1, 2000));
```

$j instead of j

Answer (score 1):

syntax error? `j` needs a `$`:

$month = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, **$j**, 1, 2000));